# Error when deleting a Row in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, datagridview

I am attempting to delete a row in my DataTable or DataViewGrid and it works, however if I select anywhere on the row other than the entire row itself it throws an error and the code stops. Is there a way to make it so when I select a part of the row and hit delete that the whole row gets deleted or at the very least a If Else statement to make it so the code does not crash if the entire row is not selected?

Here is my code deleting the row on button click.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    Dim i As Integer = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Index
    DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i)

End Sub
```

Comment: [DataGridView.CurrentCell.RowIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell) -- Possibly, remove from the source of data. Using a BindingSource, it's the `Current` data item (or the `DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to delete a Row in a DataGridView.

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1 Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
    End If
End Sub
```

Or if you want to press 'Delete' key to delete the row:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Delete Then
        If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex + 1 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Appreciate it! Works Perfectly